# Oracle Java JDK Installation

Tags: java, oracle, android-studio

I installed both Android Studio and the lates version of Oracles Java JDK 8.

When I type: java -version, it seems like I have installed java correctly:

```
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

but when I try to run my App in Android Studio via my real device (LG Nexus 5X), I receive the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> compileSdkVersion 'android-24' requires JDK 1.8 or later to compile.
```

When I check the PPA under Ubuntu Software Center, it seems like the Oracle Java Installer is activated (http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu)

Unfortunatly, I have no idea how to solve this problem.

I am using a Acer Chromebook R11 with Croton and my Java version is installed under: /usr/lib/jvm/ and I also installed /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/

Thank you for your support.

I looked up the studio.sh file in order to figure out where Android Studio searches for the Java JDK.

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Locate a JDK installation directory which will be used to run the IDE.
# Try (in order): STUDIO_JDK, ../jre, JDK_HOME, JAVA_HOME, "java" in PATH.
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
if [ -n "$STUDIO_JDK" -a -x "$STUDIO_JDK/bin/java" ]; then
  JDK="$STUDIO_JDK"
elif [ -x "$IDE_HOME/jre/jre/bin/java" ] && "$IDE_HOME/jre/jre/bin/java" -version > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
  JDK="$IDE_HOME/jre"
elif [ -n "$JDK_HOME" -a -x "$JDK_HOME/bin/java" ]; then
  JDK="$JDK_HOME"
elif [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" -a -x "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" ]; then
  JDK="$JAVA_HOME"
```

Both $JAVA_HOME and $STUDIO.JDK point to /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle.

Comment: Can you check where does Android Studio looks for JDK? It's in File -> Project Structure -> JDK Location.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think Android Studio uses Path variables in order to find the java installation path. I edited my Question above with more information though, but the error still occurs and I cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

Finally it works. I was able to fix the problem by myself. I tried to fix the problem first over settings and than via Path-variables. Actually, I just needed to go to File->Project Structure... in Android Studio and edit the app properties as well as the JDK Location.