# etc/environment == $PATH?

Tags: java, android, environment-variables

I try to fix a problem with my Android Studio Installation and for that I want to edit the $PATH variable and the $JAVA_HOME variable global and not only for one session.

As I described here ([Oracle Java JDK Installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/801104/oracle-java-jdk-installation?noredirect=1#comment1210899_801104)) my Android Studio does not find my JAVA JDK.

My question now: when I type echo $PATH, I receive:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
```

but I already edited my environment file (./etc/environment) to:

```
### begin crouton-generated environment variables
### end crouton-generated environment variables
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/usr/lib/python2.7:/usr/lib/google_appengine:/usr/lib/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.40/bin"
```

Why does the $PATH variable not change and is not affected by my edit?

Where can I edit the $JAVA_HOME variable? I cannot find the correct file for that.

Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: What is the path to your "environment file"?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is located at ./etc/environment

Comment: Do what @Zanna said in her answer and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the code in `~/.profile`. Example:

**Make a copy of path variable before doing this procedure.**

In `~/.profile`, there is a section like this:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

So, add at this at the end of the file:

```
PATH="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/usr/lib/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.40/bin:**$PATH**"

JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/usr/lib/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.40/bin"
```

The line above will add the directories in the existing path.

Comment: Your English is not perfect, but it's certainly not bad.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It worked so far. I was able to edit my PATH and JAVA_HOME variable permanently. Unfortunatly, my Android Studio error still occurs. I literally have no idea what to do now.

Comment: Did you already tried add in `/etc/environment` and do logout/login?

Comment: Yeah, more than once. I have now edited both ~/.profile and etc/environment with the same PATH + JAVA_HOME in ~/.profile.

Comment: Now it works. Had to fix two more things in Android Studio. (http://askubuntu.com/questions/801104/oracle-java-jdk-installation/803808#803808)

Answer (score 3):

You need to log out of your user session and log back in again for changes made to `/etc/environment` to take effect.

**But** you can make it work immediately by running this:

```
source /etc/environment && export PATH
```

---

I found that very useful command [here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23894456/6192153)